# php while loop and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

this is probably something very simple and i'm just making it more difficult than it has to be.  i have a php page, which just has a checkbox and a button.  when i click the button it should call my "collection.php" page and then update my index page on the status.  i took out most of my code in collection.php and my index page still doesn't update.  what am i doing wrong?? thanks in advance!

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-gb" xml:lang="en-gb">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Click trigger for image
            $("#myBtn").click(function() {
                if ($('#update').is(":checked"))
                    var update = 'on';
                else
                    var update = 'off';

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'collection.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 'update='+update,
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(output_string){
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(output_string));
                            $('#collection_status').html(''); // Clear #wines div
                            $('#collection_status').append(output_string.worked + '<br/>');
                    }, // End of success function of ajax form
                    error: function() {
                        alert("there is an issue with the collection!");
                    }
                }); // End of ajax call
                return false; // keeps the page from not refreshing 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#333333;color:white;font-family:verdana;text-transform:lowercase;">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="update" /> Update Existing<br />
        <button id="myBtn">Collect</button>
    </form>
<br />
<div id="collection_status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

collection.php

```
<?
// movie search variables
$dir = "/video/Movies/";
$movie_extensions = array('mkv','mp4','m4v','avi');
$update_movies = 0;

if(isset($_POST["update"]))
    $update_movies = $_POST["update"];

// read contents from $dir
if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            $file_info = pathinfo($file);
            $output_string['worked'] = 'found <span style="color:yellowgreen;">' . $file . '</span><br />';
            echo json_encode($output_string);
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

when i remove the echo portion from the collection script i receive a response (below works):

```
$output_string['worked'] = 'testing';
echo json_encode($output_string);
```

once i add that back to the loop it errors.

as a test i added a for loop in there - it also fails:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $output_string['worked'] = 'found <span style="color:yellowgreen;">' . $file . '</span><br />';
    echo json_encode($output_string);
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log(output_string);` the results and post it please?

Comment: hi We0, i tried adding console.log() but it wasn't returning data.  i added it right after "error: function(){" line - is that not the correct spot?

Comment: i just tried removing my response from the while loop and i do receive a response:

     $output_string['worked'] = 'testing';
     echo json_encode($output_string);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a side thought, but probably better discussed outside of commenting:

Are you aware that `$dir = "/video/Movies/";` will open the directory in the root? Instead of a subdirectory of the path your collection.php resides in. As such (on normal webservers) I hope your script won't have rights to even open that directory; thus not continuing further in your script.

Comment: hi Luceos, this is opening a temp directory i have on my server and listing the files in that directory.  it does that part correctly but are you saying it's a vulnerability?  if so, this server can only be access internally so hopefully that helps.  thanks!

Comment: I advise you not to use a custom temp directory (due to security). You don't know which users has access rights. It's better to upload from the website to the system's website directory. You can always use the directory one above the public directory. As to fixing your issue, try a folder which is publicly available for the time being by using `video/Movies/` which is under the folder of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your data attribute is seems wrong.

It should be like;

```
data: {update:update},
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  i made the changes you suggested but it still does not work as expected.  it runs the "error: function" and alerts the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should change data line.

```
 dataType: 'json',  
 data: {update:update},
 cache: false,
```

An example from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete.

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "some.php",  
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }  
}).done(function( msg ) {  
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );  
});
```

Comment: hi vishnu, thanks for the response.  so are you saying i should remove the json portion?  everything seems to work fine until i start using the while loop.

Comment: @vadderung Are you sure the issue is not with folder permissions then?

Comment: i'm not positively sure but i don't think it is permissions.  i can access the collection page directly.  i'm also not seeing any errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to receive JSON, then you need to send valid JSON.

Echoing out a series of individual JSON strings in a while loop like you are doing is going to produce invalid JSON from the client perspective.

If you are using the loop to build up a response object you should only build the object/array in the loop, then after the object/array is built `json_encode()` the entire thing and output the response.

Comment: ah i understand, mike.  the while loop takes a pretty like time to run though.  can i still send the array while the loop is running - does my questions make sense?  in other words, do i have to put the final "echo" outside of the loop? if so, the response will be pointless for me because the script will be done.  i'm using it as more of a status/progress report (see what it has done so far).  thanks for the reply!

Comment: you're exactly right, mike.  i did like you suggested and it worked.  the only issue now is it doesn't print to the screen until the script is completely done.  i need it to print to the screen as it's going through the loop. is that possible?  thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are working with a rather large document then.  I might suggest that if that is the case, and you want to show data incrementally, then you might adopt a paginated approach whereby you return X number of lines, along with some sort of flag that the javascript can interpret to indicate that it needs to start a new requests starting at the line where you last left off.

Comment: @MikeBrant `json_encode()` will output `false` when the JSON is invalid, so this probably isn't the issue. More than likely, it's failing to pass the conditionals he has set up. That said, I totally agree with the approach to building an array or object that will encode properly.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte My concern wasn't over the JSON being invalid within PHP, but rather when jQuery tries to parse what he was sending. He was echoing out a series of JSON strings to the calling script, which would not have been a single valid JSON string that jQUery could parse. There is no reason to think that `json_encode()` was not working properly as he was passing it an array.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue looks to be that you have two conditionals wrapping the response output, and you haven't properly accounted for that failure:

```
// read contents from $dir
if (is_dir($dir)){  <-- ***THIS MIGHT BE FAILING***
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){ <-- ***THIS MIGHT BE FAILING***
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){ <-- ***THIS MIGHT BE FAILING***
            $file_info = pathinfo($file);
            $output_string['worked'] = 'found <span style="color:yellowgreen;">' . $file . '</span><br />';
            echo json_encode($output_string);
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

So, you just need to account for falsy results within those conditionals:

```
// read contents from $dir
if (is_dir($dir)){  <-- ***THIS MIGHT BE FAILING***
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){ <-- ***THIS MIGHT BE FAILING***
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){ <-- ***THIS MIGHT BE FAILING***
            $file_info = pathinfo($file);
            $output_string['worked'] = 'found <span style="color:yellowgreen;">' . $file . '</span><br />';
            echo json_encode($output_string);
        }
        closedir($dh);
    } else {
      exit(json_encode(array('status' => 'Cannot open the $dir'))); <-- EXIT WITH FAIL
    }
} else {
  exit(json_encode(array('status' => '$dir is not a dir'))); <-- EXIT WITH FAIL
}
```

This should at least give you an idea of what is failing... Good luck. :)

Comment: thanks a bunch, matthew.  i am getting a response when i hit the page directly but it seems like maybe it's an invalid json response like mike is suggesting.

Comment: @vadderung hmmm possibly. json_encode will just output "NULL" when it's invalid.

Comment: what do you think about my response to mike below?  is this possible?

Comment: @vadderung I just responded to his answer. Have you tried my suggestion? Is it outputting any of the failure messages I put in place?

Comment: no it isn't outputting any of the failure messages.  it just fails until i move it out of the loop.

Comment: @vadderung Then `($file = readdir($dh)) !== false` is probably failing as your while loop conditional.